# Proving an inequality about a set of combinations.

Tags: combinatorics, inequality

Suppose $A$ is a set of $r$ combinations of an $n$ set, with $\alpha \cap \beta \neq \phi$, whenever $\alpha, \beta \in A$. Show that $$|A| \leq \binom{n-1}{r-1}$$ if $r \leq \frac n2$.

What does this question mean exactly ? Is it the set of all $r$ combinations, such that no two of them are mutually disjoint ?

The hint said to consider $\partial^{n-2r}B$, where $B$ is the set of complements of $A$. I don't know how to apply partial differentiation to combinatorics. Please help.

Comment: I think you mean $\alpha \cap \beta$, not $\alpha \cup \beta$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Yes, I do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A=\{A_1,\ldots,A_s\}$ be a family of subsets of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$.  Then, $A$ is said to be an *intersecting family* if any two elements in $A$ have a nontrivial intersection.  If we also place the restriction that all subsets in $A$ have the same cardinality, say $A$ is an intersecting family of $r$-subsets of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ , then how large can $A$ be?

One way to generate an intersecting family of $r$-subsets of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$  is to pick an element, say $1$, to include in each of the $r$-subsets.  The remaining $r-1$ elements can be chosen in ${n-1 \choose r-1}$ ways. Thus, there exists an intersecting family of $r$-subsets of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ of cardinality ${n-1 \choose r-1}$, namely the set of all $r$-subsets which contain the element $1$.  The Erdos-Ko-Rado theorem asserts that this value is the maximal size  of an intersecting family of $r$-subsets and that every intersecting family of $r$-subsets of maximal size is exactly of the form just mentioned: the set of all $r$-subsets which contain one particular element.

The symbol $\partial$ is probably the notation for something like the *shadow* (not the partial derivative).  You can look at your reference (or a text on set-systems) for the exact definition.

Comment: Wow. Thanks. I'll need some time to read and understand this. Now, I understood why $\binom{n-1}{r-1}$ is a possible enumeration of intersecting subsets. But, how to prove that this is the maximum number ?

Comment: Do you have a lot of experience with combinatorics ?

Comment: Your Eleanor definition helped me understand. Can you explain what the condition $n \gt 2r$ has to do with it ?

Comment: *elegant ${}{}$

Comment: If $r > n/2$, then an $r$-subset contains more than half of the elements of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ and so any two $r$-subsets will intersect. Hence, the maximal size of an intersecting family of $r$-subsets is trivially ${n \choose r}$.  So the $r > n/2$ case is trivial.

Comment: For a proof that that is the maximal number, you can look anywhere for a proof of the so-called Erdos-Ko-Rado theorem.

Comment: What's an Eleanor definition?

Comment: I already clarified I meant elegant definition. By the way, what is your mathematical background ?

Comment: This terminology (of intersecting families) can be found in the text titled "Combinatorics: set systems, hypergraphs, families of vectors and combinatorial probability" (by Bollobas, 1986).

Comment: Do you know what the partial differentiator operator means in this case ?

Comment: @user230452: See the answer to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/530790/shadow-of-a-set-system).

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I don't see any direct link between that question and mine. Please elaborate.

Comment: @AshwinGanesan Thanks. Bollobos really is a good mathematician ! Are you also a mathematician ?

Comment: @user230452: I was answering your question immediately above my comment. The answer in question explains the $\partial$ notation for the shadow.

Comment: I finally have understood what a shadow is. Can you tell me how to reconcile the hint given with the proof ?